# HTML5 warning when checking R package

Tags: r-package, cran

I am trying to build an R package for deployment on CRAN, but when I run the CRAN checks I get HTLM5 related warnings. For example :

Warning:  attribute "width" not allowed for HTML5

Note - the HTML is automatically generated from an Rd file during the build / check process, so the "offending" attributes get added by the build system.

Has anyone else come across this problem.

Many thanks.